# How to get the binding address from a WSDL file

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I generated a proxy class given a URL to a WSDL.

I need to let the end-user change the service's URL to his specific URL, like this:

```
ServiceProxy.Url = [URL set by end-user];
```

The issue is that this URL should not point to the WSDL, it should be the binding address which is found within the WSDL (wsdl:service -> wsdl:port -> wsdl:address) (this is a SAP web service, I understand that is why I must use the binding address).

I am thinking of using the XDocument class to get that value, but I am wondering if there is any "built-in" functionality in WCF or web services to get the binding address. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a small function in VB.NET (sorry!) based on code at [Parse Complex WSDL Parameter Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452724/parse-complex-wsdl-parameter-information-in-c-sharp) . Hope it helps.

```
Public Function GetURLFromWSDL(ByVal wsdl As String) As String
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(wsdl)
    request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=""utf-8"""
    request.Method = "GET"
    request.Accept = "text/xml"

    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim service As ServiceDescription = ServiceDescription.Read(stream)
            Dim binding As SoapAddressBinding = service.Services(0).Ports(0).Extensions(0)
            Return binding.Location
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```