# Get WebMethod parameter list

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, webmethod

I'm working on a project that call a `WebMethod` dynamically after validating its parameters by knowing its URL.

Here's my attempt:

```
[WebMethod]
public string CalledService (string myText, int count)
{
    return myText;
}
```

and all I know is its URL

```
http://localhost:29740/OnewayWebserviceCall/WebService.asmx?op=CalledService
```

I need a function that returns something like `{"myText","count"}`

I tried to download the URL string and search for the parameters in it but I need something more time efficient.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I need to pass requests to any webservice, I'm not the one who created those webservices.

Comment: I totally misunderstood your question, you're looking for a [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language). You don't have to parse that by hand, see for example [Parse Complex WSDL Parameter Information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452724/parse-complex-wsdl-parameter-information).

Comment: I recommend that you read the WSDL of the service, which includes information about all the operations and messages. See the [ServiceDescription class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedescription.aspx)

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks a lot I was searching for something like that