# Operation parameters types are null in imported service metadata (WSDL)

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I am trying to import a WCF service operations list. What I need to obtain is the name of each operation, its parameters names and types and the result type.

The service I am testing this with is a simple one, with one operation accepting a parameter of type int.

The WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="Service1" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:3657/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:3657/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetData"/>
    </wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="IService1">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" message="tns:IService1_GetData_InputMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetData_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" type="tns:IService1">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="Service1">
        <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:3657/Service1.svc"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The xsd0 look like this:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <xs:element name="GetData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="GetDataResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="GetDataResult" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am using the [System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlImporter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlimporter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class like this:

```
MetadataExchangeClient mexClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(
    new Uri("http://localhost:3657/Service1.svc?singleWsdl"),
    MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet);

mexClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
MetadataSet metaDocs = mexClient.GetMetadata();
WsdlImporter importer = new WsdlImporter(metaDocs);
```

Next, I am getting the contract list and iterating through it:

```
 Collection<ContractDescription> contracts = importer.ImportAllContracts();

    foreach (ContractDescription contract in contracts)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Contract name:" + contract.Name);

        foreach (OperationDescription operation in contract.Operations)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("\tOperation name:" + operation.Name);

            foreach (MessageDescription message in operation.Messages)
            {
                MessageBodyDescription body = message.Body;

                Debug.WriteLine("\t\t\tMessage wrapper name: " + body.WrapperName);

                foreach (MessagePartDescription part in body.Parts)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tPart name: " + part.Name);
                    Debug.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tPart type: " + part.Type);
                }

                if (body.ReturnValue != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tReturn value type: " + body.ReturnValue.Type);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The result should be the operations info printed. I am getting the following output:

```
Contract name: IService1
    Operation name: GetData
            Message wrapper name: GetData
                Part name: value
                Part type: 
            Message wrapper name: GetDataResponse
                Return value type:
```

As you can see, the parts corresponding to operation parameters contain null in their Type property. Similarly, the return value type is also null.

I examined the contents of the contracts collection and in every place where some type information should be, it's empty (like the [OperationDescription.KnownTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.servicemodel.description.operationdescription.knowntypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property).

I tried the approach from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452724/parse-complex-wsdl-parameter-information) question, but it fails at:

```
foreach (object item in xmlSchema.Items)
```

where the Items collection is empty.

Does anyone know, why the types information is missing? Everything else seems to be present.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I found that the type information is present in a non-public property of the message body part "BaseType". Why is this private? Any way to access that? (Not involving creating an actual proxy, which I don't want to do at this point.)

Comment: I wonder that myself, have you figured out a way to get the Type without reading private property `BaseType`?

Comment: @JobaDiniz Unfortunately not. Other than using reflection to read `BaseType`, you seem to have the option with `DynamicProxy`, where you get the result type via reflection as well, using `MethodInfo` of the desired operation. If you don't need the proxy to call the service, I'd go with reading `BaseType`, 'cause it's probably better performance-wise.