# How to get operations parameters in wsdl

Tags: c#, wsdl

How can I get SOAP operation request and response parameters by port types in WSDL, but programmatically. I benefit from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452724/parse-complex-wsdl-parameter-information), it is working without problem but also not my solution.

Comment: Writing an answer would be a project in itself, but here's some food for research: Parse the xml to find the port types and the operations they contain, store the information off in your choice of data structure. Programmatically run svcutil.exe on the wsdl to generate classes. Use the Microsoft .Net Compiler Services (Roslyn) to build a semantic model and locate the methods and inspect them for parameters.